# Intersect 2 lists in prolog

Tags: list, prolog

My task is to intersect 2 lists in prolog. However I can't seem to find a reason for my functions not to work . I don't know what prolog wants from me. This is my attempt at solving the task:

```
write_list([]).


write_list([Head|Tail]) :-
  write(Head), nl,
  write_list(Tail).

intersect(L,[],X) :- write_list(X).
intersect([],L,X) :- write_list(X).

intersect([H1|T1],[H2|T2], X) :-
    H1 == H2,
    append([H1],X,Y),
    intersect(T1,T2,Y).

intersect([H1|T1],[H2|T2], X) :-
    H1 > H2,
    intersect(T1,[H2|T2],X).

intersect([H1|T1],[H2|T2], X) :-
    H1 < H2,
    intersect([H1|T1],T2,X).
```

I try calling it `intersect([1,2,3],[2,3,4],X).` and the answer I get is `[]`. Can anyone tell me why ?

Update1: Also as a side question how can I make prolog print that X without me calling write_list(X). I saw that some functions return the extra argument...

Comment: You don't have a base case for what happens when your recursion gets down to the empty list. What's the result of `intersect([], X, ...)` or `intersect(X, [], ...)`? Not only will your result be `[]` in your example, but it will just flat out fail if the lists are different in length. And a couple of side notes: `append([H1], X, Y)` can be simplified to just, `[H1|X] = Y`, and you you can use `dif(H1, H2)` instead of separate checks for `H1` and `H2`. Using `dif/2` also allows this to work for non-numeric elements, among other things.

Comment: Ah you are right, when I deleted out of anger I deleted those cases also. Here is my updated code. The result is the same : []

Comment: The base cases are wrong. You have to think about the meaning of `intersect(X, Y, Z)`, which is, *`Z` is the intersection of `X` and `Y`*. Certainly, `X` is not the intersection of `L` and `[]` unless `X = []`. The recursion will "unwind" to give you the result. Your base cases are what happens before all the "unwinding" occurs. You avoid the `write` just by calling `intersect([1,2,3],[2,3,4],X).` and prolog will tell you what `X` is.

Comment: ok so the base cases should be something like: intersect([],L,[]). intersect(L,[],[]). because the value that X should have is [] in this case yes?

Comment: Or just `intersect([], _, [])` and `intersect(_, [], [])` since you don't care what `L` is. And your main case needs to be refigured since it's logically not true. If `Y` is `[H1|X]` (which is what you get for that `append`, then `Y` can't necessarily also be the result of the intersection of `T1` and `T2` because, in that case, `T1` and `T2` would both need to contain `H1`.

Comment: Let's say that my base case is intersect([H1|T1],[H2|T2], X) :-H1 == H2,
intersect(T1,T2,[H1|X]). This says: if h1 and h2 are equal then intersect(first list without the element, second list without the element, old intersection + element which was equal). What am I mistaken ?

Comment: `intersect([H1|T1],[H2|T2], X) :-H1 == H2, intersect(T1,T2,[H1|X])` is not a base case. It's a recursive case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92599/discussion-between-lucian-tarna-and-lurker).

Comment: I don't quite get it . So I need a base case that would mean the intersection of T1 and T2 ? Seems like that is the result to me . O I should write it intersect([H1|T1],[H1|T2], X) :-intersect(T1,T2,[H1|X]). But this still isn't enough.  The result is still [] , well this is sad

Answer (score 1):

Let's think of the problem in logical language. The meaning of `intersect(X, Y, Z)` might be, `Z` is the intersection of `X` and `Y`. So the base case of `intersect(L, [], X) :- write_list(X).` could not be correct unless `X = []`. For the base case, we might say, then:

```
intersect([], _, []).
```

Since *anything* (`_`) intersect with the empty set (`[]`) is empty.

Then for the recursive case, you have:

```
intersect([H1|T1],[H2|T2], X) :-
    H1 == H2,
    append([H1],X,Y),
    intersect(T1,T2,Y).
```

Let's simplify a little, since we can put the unification of the heads of the lists in the head of the predicate, and we don't need `append` since `append([H1], X, Y)` is the same as, `[H1|X] = Y`:

```
intersect([H|T1],[H|T2], X) :-
    intersect(T1, T2, [H|X]).
```

Already we have some trouble since the recursive call should have the shorter list as the result. It was probably meant as:

```
intersect([H|T1],[H|T2], [H|X]) :-
    intersect(T1, T2, X).
```

But even so, although improved, it's making the assumption that same elements will be in tandem with each other in the two lists, which may not be the case.

One alternative approach would be to use `member/2` and `delete/3`:

```
intersect([], _, []).
intersect([H|X], Y, Z) :-
    member(H, Y)
->  delete(Y, H, Y1),
    intersect(X, Y1, Z1),
    Z = [H|Z1]
;   intersect(X, Y, Z).
```

Here, if the current head of the first list is a member of the second, we remove all occurrences of this element from the second list and determine the intersection of that result with the rest of the first list, which becomes the tail of the result of the clause. Otherwise, we intersect the tail of the first list with the second.

Note that this is an somewhat imperative (and probably a little naive) approach to the problem, and works in the imperative sense, "Given two lists X and Y, find their intersection". But it's not relational or declarative ("Z is the intersection of X and Y"), which would be Prolog's real strength.

As far as your question about avoiding "writing" the results, you can see when you execute a predicate in prolog, it will show you already the possible instanatiations of variables that make it true. So no writing necessary.